# Unable to install Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller driver for centOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, drivers, linux-kernel, ethernet

I've installed CentOS 6.3. However, **eth0 does not show up on ifconfig**.

So I figured out that I need to install alx Ethernet driver from [here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx).
Since my internet is not working, as ethernet drivers are not installed, I've installed Development Tools from the DVD.

**Steps performed:**

1. ./scripts/driver-select alx
2. On 'make' I get this error. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5669506/

How do I solve this issue? Would be grateful for any kind of help. Thanks.